# How to apply function in DataFrame.query in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply round function while using dataframe.query

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([(1.2,2.3,12),(2.7,2.3,13),(1.9,5.3,14), (1.2,4.6,15)], columns=['val1', 'val2','val3'])
```

Data frame looks as follows:

```
  val1  val2  val3
0   1.2   2.3    12
1   2.7   2.3    13
2   1.9   5.3    14
3   1.2   4.6    15
```

I want rows where round(val1) >2
I tried function as follows - but results in error:

```
 df.query("val1.round()>2")
```

Is there a way to use math functions like round, abs on columns without creating intermediate columns in df.query

Is there a way to use df.query and get final output as follows:

```
 val1  val2  val3
1   2.7   2.3    13
2   1.9   5.3    14
```

Comment: What is the error? That `df.query()` line works for me.

Comment: Also note to get the two rows you're looking for, you need `>= 2`.

Comment: I get following error                                                                                                      
 >>> df.query("val1.round()>=2")
  File "C:\Users\mehta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\engines.py", line 36, in _check_ne_builtin_clash
    names = expr.names
  File "C:\Users\mehta\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py", line 834, in names
    return frozenset(term.name for term in com.flatten(self.terms))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: I can't reproduce this error with the code you've provided. But it seems to be a type error. Try this: `df.val1 = pd.to_numeric(df.val1)` before query.

Comment: still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query seems fine, but you can try this too:

```py
df[df.val1.round() > 2]
```

Comment: I want to use df.query